# "Redline" explanation

Tags: meaning-in-context, business-language, idiom-meaning

Expedite the process by requiring the Customer to “redline” any changes to drafts throughout the review process, and be careful not to send any contract drafts to the Customer that contain internal  comments unless Legal provides clearance to do so.

So, how to read "redline",  to eliminate or something else?

Comment: Voting to close for lack of research, but you're looking for [definition #3](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/redlining).  [Example](https://www.papercheck.com/microsoft-word-track-changes/2007-microsoft-word-track-changes-instructions/).

Comment: @Lynn I had  looked up in the dictionary, and  I was still confused in the context,1 (在表上) 用红线予以注销
2 指出 (飞机之) 最大的安全飞行速度
The bomber is ~ at 700 miles an hour. 
那轰炸机最大安全速度为每小时700哩
3 不使起飞 (开航) 
~ an airplane 
使飞机停飞 u won't know how it fell as a non-native speaker. Thank you @deadrat!

Comment: I can sympathize with the plight of a non-native speaker, but nonetheless the "rules" of SE state that you must actually show the research in your question.   For instance, citing a dictionary entry and saying what about it confused you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Redline* means to highlight changes to drafts.  Here, the reference to changes the customer wishes to make to the draft document, which is likely a preliminary wording of an agreement or contract.  Red is a traditional color of warning, and the company wants to be able to see clearly the parts of the document with which the customer is in disagreement.  You may have confused this term with <del>strikeout</del> type, which indicates language to be eliminated.

Be aware that the term **redline** has different meanings in different contexts.  For instance, it's the point on a meter indicating danger.  If the meter is a tachometer, then the engine is in a dangerous state when the tach **redlines**.  Banks have been known to exclude certain neighborhoods for consideration for mortgages, and this is known as **redlining** since presumably the banks had maps with the forbidden neighborhoods outlines in red ink.